# Postgres Proxy User authentication

Tags: postgresql, security, authentication, database-connection

Any way to get Proxy User authentication done in PostgreSql?
As from Oracles
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/proxy-users-and-connect-through#proxy-user-and-connect-through

Comment: Do you want the network proxy authentication or the proxy user system like in oracle?

Comment: No, not _network_ proxy, but  Proxy User authentication as from Oracle
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/proxy-users-and-connect-through#proxy-user-and-connect-through

Comment: you can try to implement the same with roles and groups

Comment: Answer to pretty similar question you can find here
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77704/proxy-authentication-for-postgesql